# Angular Page is showing blank in Browser first time and showing content on refresh url

Tags: angular, iis

We had developed the angular 14 application and deployed in IIS 10 in UAT server.

On clicking the URL first time in browser, it showing blank page and if we refresh the URL, it is working.

Kindly guide us what could be the issue.

**VS Code:**

> ng build --base-href "TestSite"

Copied the folder dist folder and deployed in IIS server. And added the web.config file as well.

**IIS 10:**
Installed URLRewrite2 module downloaded from official IIS site

**Web Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: When you first visit the URL what is in the HTML source? If that angular app is at the root URL then you shouldn't need to specify the `--base-href` option at all since the default it work there.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to view the detailed request process, what changes will happen when the url is refreshed.